# Excel Command Button to click event

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel worksheet and have some already operating button called as "Enable". I want to create new command button which hen clicked will click on this "Enable" button . What should be VB code for that .
I wrote as follows:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets
End Sub
```

But it is not writing on that "Enable" button here.

I request your help to write from one command button on excel which will will click on this already created button called "Enable"

Please help me in this.

Comment: This "Enable" button is already there on excel sheet and it is getting clicked once we press it. but I want to operate ths button with anothr command button created on excel

Comment: Could you share your code correctly pls (with formatting)? Thanks Dominique.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve (edit) question!

Comment: Dear Sir,  I hv not written any code yet . Plz help me with the code for this.

Comment: Plz help me in this as I get stuck completely

Comment: I request you to send me the sample code here